# Re-populating worksheet values back into textboxes within a userform upon userform Initialization

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Wondering if someone can help me reverse the below code.  Essentially, I have a userform with a combobox that generates from a list of names from a worksheet column "A".  Upon submit the selected items from userform are populated to the worksheet to the row of the corresponding name from the combobox. 


I am hoping to somehow reverse the code below so I can place it in "UserForm_Initialize()" to regenerate saved values back to the texboxes on the form if user closes and reopens the same day.  I have a current date textbox called "currentDate". So basically if Date = currentDate.Text Than...add cell value back to textboxes.

```
      Dim dn As Worksheet: Set dn = Sheets("DailyNumbers")
      Dim EmptyRow As Long
      Dim FoundVal As Range
      EmptyRow = dn.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

      ' *** Check combobox selection ***
      If procNamecombobox.ListIndex > -1 Then
      Set FoundVal = dn.Range("A1:A" & EmptyRow).Find (procNamecombobox.Value) 'find Combobox value in Column A
      If Not FoundVal Is Nothing Then 'if found
        dn.Range("B" & FoundVal.Row).Value = currentDate.Text
        dn.Range("C" & FoundVal.Row).Value = completeCount.Text 'use that  row to populate cells
        dn.Range("D" & FoundVal.Row).Value = handledCount.Text
        dn.Range("E" & FoundVal.Row).Value = wipCount.Text
        dn.Range("F" & FoundVal.Row).Value = suspendCount.Text
        Else 'if not found use EmptyRow to populate Cells
        dn.Range("A" & EmptyRow).Value = procNamecombobox.Value
        dn.Range("B" & EmptyRow).Value = currentDate.Text
        dn.Range("C" & EmptyRow).Value = completeCount.Text
        dn.Range("D" & EmptyRow).Value = handledCount.Text
        dn.Range("E" & EmptyRow).Value = wipCount.Text
        dn.Range("F" & EmptyRow).Value = suspendCount.Text
     End If
Else
    MsgBox "Please select your name"
End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use something like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim f As Range

    With Worksheets("DailyNumbers") 'reference wanted sheet
        Set f = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Find(Date, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) 'search referenced sheet column B for current date
    End With
    If Not f Is Nothing Then ' if current date found
        With Me 'reference userform
            .completeCount.Text = f.Offset(, 1).value
            .handledCount.Text = f.Offset(, 2).value
            .wipCount.Text = f.Offset(, 3).value
            .suspendCount.Text = f.Offset(, 4).value
        End With
    End If

    'your other code to fill listbox
    With Worksheets("NamesArchive") ' just a guess...
        Me.procNamecombobox.List = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))) 'fill combobox with referenced sheet column A values from rows 1 down to last not empty one
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, your code could be refactored as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' just a guess...

    Dim dn As Worksheet: Set dn = Sheets("DailyNumbers")
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim foundRng As Range

    With Me
        With .procNamecombobox
            If .ListIndex = -1 Then
                MsgBox "Please select your name"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            emptyRow = dn.Cells(dn.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Set foundRng = dn.Range("A1:A" & emptyRow).Find(.value) 'find Combobox value in Column A
            If foundRng Is Nothing Then 'if no entry with input name
                dn.Range("A" & emptyRow).value = .value 'fill column A first empty with input name
            Else 'otherwise
                emptyRow = foundRng.Row 'set found cell row index as the one to write in 
            End If
        End With

        Intersect(dn.Range("B:F"), dn.Rows(emptyRow)).value = Array(.currentDate.Text, .completeCount.Text, .handledCount.Text, .wipCount.Text, .suspendCount.Text) 'fill columns B to F proper row with textboxes values
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To help get you started:

**A)**
Determine if there is a cell in column B with the current date. If so, locate it and use the .Row property to save the row number to a variable.

*(There are a couple of range functions (.Find, .Search) that you can use to locate a cell with a particular value. For date's, [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/redirect-to/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpearson.com%2Fexcel%2FDateTimeVBA.htm%23Finding) has some helpful information.)*

**A.5)** From the above link, if the dates are in Excel as serial dates -- not text -- then you can use

```
Set FoundCell = Range("A1:A100").Find _
   (what:=Date,lookin:=xlFormulas)
```

to find the current date in column A from rows 1 to 100. VBA has a function `Date()` which returns the current day's date. `Now()` returns the current date and time, while `Time()` returns the current time.

**B)**
Set the .text values of the Text/Combo boxes to the values of the cells

*(These can be located with a concatenation of the correct column with the saved row variable from earlier. Similar to how you located the cells to save the values initially)*

If you're stuck on how to do a particular step or process, and can't find an existing Q&A with information, you can ask for elaboration.

Comment: Thank you but I am unsure of how to determine if the cell in column B is the current date?

Comment: @user3806255 I edited to include a link, and some explanation in point A.5